# Runtime error due to incompatibility with ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh, glyph

Here is the code where I am getting an error while using the CDS(Column Data Structure).

Here is the error that I am getting:
[image: RuntimeError screenshot]

Any ideas?

```
#Plotting flower species

#Importing libraries
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers
from bokeh.models import Range1d, PanTool, ResetTool, HoverTool, ColumnDataSource, LabelSet

colormap={'setosa':'red','versicolor':'green','virginica':'blue'}
flowers['color']=[colormap[x] for x in flowers['species']]

setosa=ColumnDataSource(flowers[flowers["species"]=="setosa"])
versicolor=ColumnDataSource(flowers[flowers["species"]=="versicolor"])
virginica=ColumnDataSource(flowers[flowers["species"]=="virginica"])

#Define the output file path
output_file("iris.html")

#Create the figure object
f=figure()

#adding glyphs
f.circle(x="petal_length", y="petal_width",
     size=[i*4 for i in setosa.data["sepal_width"]],
     fill_alpha=0.2,color="color",line_dash=[5,3],legend='Setosa',source=setosa)

f.circle(x="petal_length", y="petal_width",
     size=[i*4 for i in setosa.data["sepal_width"]],
     fill_alpha=0.2,color="color",line_dash=[5,3],legend='Versicolor',source=versicolor)

f.circle(x="petal_length", y="petal_width",
     size=[i*4 for i in setosa.data["sepal_width"]],
     fill_alpha=0.2,color="color",line_dash=[5,3],legend='Virginica',source=virginica)

#Save and show the figure
show(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `size` column in the data frame:

```
flowers['size'] = [i*4 for i in flowers["sepal_width"]]
```

So that it is in the `ColumnDataSource` that you make later. Then use the column name with the glyph functions:

```
f.circle(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", size="size", color="color",
         fill_alpha=0.2, line_dash=[5,3],legend='Setosa', source=setosa)
```

Howevever, you can also just pass the DataFrames, and a CDS will be created for you automatically, which is simpler. Here is a complete version:

```
#Plotting flower species

#Importing libraries
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers

colormap={'setosa':'red', 'versicolor':'green', 'virginica':'blue'}
flowers['color'] = [colormap[x] for x in flowers['species']]
flowers['size'] = [i*4 for i in flowers["sepal_width"]]

setosa = flowers[flowers["species"]=="setosa"]
versicolor = flowers[flowers["species"]=="versicolor"]
virginica = flowers[flowers["species"]=="virginica"]

#Define the output file path
output_file("iris.html")

#Create the figure object
f=figure()

#adding glyphs
f.circle(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", size="size", color="color",
     fill_alpha=0.2,line_dash=[5,3], legend='Setosa', source=setosa)

f.circle(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", size="size", color="color",
     fill_alpha=0.2,line_dash=[5,3],legend='Versicolor', source=versicolor)

f.circle(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", size="size", color="color",
     fill_alpha=0.2,line_dash=[5,3],legend='Virginica', source=virginica)

#Save and show the figure
show(f)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton... @bigreddot I was getting confused with the CDS , with your explanation I now understand that what was I missing by not creating the size...

Comment: I'm glad it helped! If you can upvote/mark correct, that will help other people find the answer.